# Django STATIC FILES location CONFUSION

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've been learning Django for a while now, but the static files topic makes me doubt about WHERE and HOW they should be placed and it's configuration in settings.py.

Lets say I start a Django project called "WEBSITE" and create an app called "BLOG".

From what I've seen and read, people use 2 different "ways" to place/save their static files (css, images, javascript) and templates.

```
Method #1 (the asterix means "Directory" and dash means its a "file"):

      In my base.html template I use:
    
      {% load static %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">

      And on the other templates I used:

      {% extends 'BLOG/base.html'%}
      {% load static %}

Here is my file structure from what I have read in the documentation:

*WEBSITE
    *BLOG
        *Migrations
        *static
            *BLOG
                *images
                    -image_01.png
                    -image_02.png
                *css
                    -style.css
                *js
        *templates
            *BLOG
                -base.html
                -index.html
                -contact.html
                -about.html
        -__init__.py
        -admin.py
        -apps.py
        -forms.py
        -models.py
        -tests.py
        -urls.py
        -views.py
    *WEBSITE
        -__init__.py
        -asgi.py
        -settings.py
        -urls.py
        -wsgi.py
    -db.sqlite3
    -manage.py
```

In the setting.py app, theres only:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and it loads the images and css just fine...

That was the method I learned when reading the documentation, but when I watched some youtube tutorials, they used something else, which is the other method#2:

```
    Method#2(the asterix means "Directory" and dash means its a "file"):

    *WEBSITE
        *static
            *BLOG
                *css
                    -style.css
                *js
                *img
                    -image_01.png
                    -image_02.png
                    -image_03.png
        *BLOG
            *Migrations
            *templates
                *BLOG
                    -base.html
                    -index.html
                    -contact.html
                    -about.html
            -__init__.py
            -admin.py
            -apps.py
            -forms.py
            -models.py
            -tests.py
            -urls.py
            -views.py
        *WEBSITE
            -__init__.py
            -asgi.py
            -settings.py
            -urls.py
            -wsgi.py
        -db.sqlite3
        -manage.py
```

In method#2, the 'static' directory is in the same directory as the app 'BLOG', the only directory that remained the same is the 'templates' folder and its html files.

Now, in method#2 setting.py, they make the following changes:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
        ]
```

And, just like in method#1 also they use:

```
      In the base.html template in method#2 they use:
    
      {% load static %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">

       And on the other templates they also use:

       {% extends 'BLOG/base.html'%}
       {% load static %}
```

---

So, as you see, there is my confusion...what is the difference between the 2 of them?

I know that if you have multiple apps, you need to do this:

```
    -for images, css and js(static files):

    APP_1/static/APP_1/img/image_01.png          
    APP_2/static/APP_2/img/image_01.png
    APP_3/static/APP_3/img/image_01.png


    -for your templates:

    APP_1/templates/APP_1/about.hmtl          
    APP_2/templates/APP_2/about.html
    APP_3/templates/APP_3/about.html
```

Why do some people use method#1 and some method#2?
As I said, I'm new to Django and programming, so please be patient with me....I really want to learn this whole 'static files' confusion!

Thanks everyone!